# android - How can I open a new activity inside of a new task and let it occur behind the current task?

Tags: android

When using chrome on android 6.0, I can long press a link, select "open in new tab" and open it into another task behind current task.

Now I need to do something familiar, but I can't find out how to let my activity start inside a new task and let the task start behind the current task with the fancy animation.

I found

`public static final int ANIM_LAUNCH_TASK_BEHIND = 7;`

in ActivityOptions.java and there is a javadoc:

```
/**
 * If set along with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT then the task being launched will not be
 * presented to the user but will instead be only available through the recents task list.
 * In addition, the new task wil be affiliated with the launching activity's task.
 * Affiliated tasks are grouped together in the recents task list.
 *
 * <p>This behavior is not supported for activities with {@link
 * android.R.styleable#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode launchMode} values of
 * <code>singleInstance</code> or <code>singleTask</code>.
 */
public static ActivityOptions makeTaskLaunchBehind() {
    final ActivityOptions opts = new ActivityOptions();
    opts.mAnimationType = ANIM_LAUNCH_TASK_BEHIND;
    return opts;
}
```

So it seems android support this feature, but I couldn't find out how to use this. Has anybody done something similar? How can I open a new activity inside of a new task and let it occur behind the current task?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some search in source code, I find the animation type can be specified by the options passed in startActivity...but the key and value to request this feature seems not to be public since I can't access them directly. But, after all, I can request this feature with following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("android:activity.animType", 7);
startActivity(intent, bundle);
```

Now I wonder is there a better and more standard way of requesting this feature? It looks dangerous to use a literal string instead of a constant field of some class.